# Importing convention in python

Tags: python-2.7, import, module, package

I have a question about the convention of importing own modules in python, i am a newbie in python. Say I have a directory called `my_directory` with 2 files in it: `for_importing.py` and `main.py`. The code in `for_importing.py` is:

```
import math

def l(n):
    print math.log10(n)
```

and in `main.py` i have:

```
import for_import

for_import.l(1000)
print "############"
print math.log10(1000)
```

which causes an error since math is not imported in main.py as well. This means imported modules/packages in `for_importing` modules will not be accessible in the file which imports `for_importing` and i have to explicitly `import` the modules by hand again (in my example i have to `import math` in both of my files in order to use it in both files). Is this the right way of doing such multiple `import`s?

Comment: Yes, you need to import wherever you need to use the module. The second and subsequent imports are all free in terms of time and memory, though :-)

Comment: From the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Explicit is better than implicit".